# How to set alpha order in data

Tags: php

HI i get the  data but not in  alphabtical order  here is my code

```
$result=mysql_query($query);
if($result)
{
$row=mysql_fetch_row($result);
$message=array("realname"=>$row[0],"currentsongid"=>$row[1],"currentsonglistid"=>$row[2],"songlistname"=>$row[3],"songtitle"=>$row[4],"songartist"=>$row[5]);

}
else
{
$message=array("message"=>"error in code");
}
echo json_encode($message);
}
```

plz tell me how to arrange data in alphabtical order

Comment: $message data should be alphabetical

Answer (score 3):

You should do so in your query with MySQL's `ORDER BY`, not PHP.

Read more from the docs about [sorting rows](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/sorting-rows.html).